# Errors Thrown From View Component don't Show Error Page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 application that is configured to show an Error Page in Production or use DeveloperExeptionPage.

If I throw an error directly from a controller, this works fine.
However if I throw an error from a ViewComponent it does not work.  I get a blank page in the browser and when I look in the Developer Tools on Chrome, the page request just says status "failed" and "GET (page url) 200 ()" in the console.

In IE, I get "This Page cannot be display" with "Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your ViewComponent's class file and some code that shows how you are invoking your ViewComponent.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is going wrong without seeing your ViewComponent's class and how you are invoking your view component.

That being said, the following works in a brand new application created with `dotnet new mvc` (and version 2.1.3 of the SDK).

**.\Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

**.\Views\Shared\Components\FooBar\Default.cshtml**

```
<p>FooBarViewComponent</p>
```

**.\Views\Home\Index.cshtml**

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("FooBar")
```

**.\FooBarViewComponent.cs**

```
public class FooBarViewComponent : ViewComponent {
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync() {
        throw new System.Exception("Exception in FooBar");
        await Task.Delay(0);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Navigating to the home page reliably renders the "/Home/Error" view.